# Is Java 8 findFirst().isPresent() more efficient than count() > 0?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given I have a stream `Stream<T> stream = list.stream().filter(some predicate)`  where the list is very large, is it more efficient to check whether the stream is non-empty by doing: `stream.count() > 0` or by doing: `stream.findFirst().isPresent()`?

Comment: It depends on which `List` implementation it is, but it isn't even comparable, as it moves you in the stream.

Comment: For infinite streams, `count()` will not even terminate; even for finite streams, it will have to traverse the entire stream before returning.  Whereas `findFirst()` or `findAny()` or `anyMatch(e -> true)` are short-circuiting, they stop when they find an element.

Comment: The real lesson here is that the right question is not about efficiency, but about correctness.  Using `findXxx` or `xxxMatch` is better not because they are more efficient, but because they're closer to expressing the property you actually want to know about.  That they happen to be more efficient is merely a pleasant side-effect of having posed a better query to the library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If all you want to know, is whether there is a match, you should use
`list.stream().anyMatch(some predicate)`, not only because it is more efficient, but also, because it is the correct idiom for expressing you intention.

As said by others, `anyMatch` is short-circuiting, which implies that it will stop at the first match, whereas `count` will, as the name suggests, count *all* matches before returning. Depending on the stream contents, this can make a huge performance difference. But note, that you can make `count` similarly efficient, by using 
`list.stream().filter(some predicate).limit(1).count() > 0`

Then, it will also stop after the first occurrence, but, as said, `anyMatch` is still the preferred way to express that you are interested in whether there is *any match*. Things change, when the task is to find out whether there are *at least* `n` matches. Then, `.limit(n).count() > n-1` (or `>= n`) becomes the natural idiom.

Note that `findFirst()` differs from the other solution because its answer depends on the ordering. So if you only want to know whether there is a match, you should use `findAny()` instead. Still, there is a theoretical difference due to the requirement of returning the matching value, compared to just telling whether there is a match, like `anyMatch` does, though currently that difference lies only in the construction of an `Optional` instance, hence is negligible.

But since you are programming against an API to encode your intention, you should not use `find…` when you only want to know whether there is a match. `anyMatch` clearly expresses your intention and might have an even higher benefit in future implementations or more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend using `list.stream().anyMatch(some predicate)`, which is a terminal operation for exactly this case. It's not only more efficient than `stream.count()`, but it won't hang on infinite streams.

Comment: @Holger It sounds like you're disagreeing with something I said.

Comment: Perhaps I misread something in your answer yesterday, I guess, I overlooked the “only”… I did not downvote, in case you’re wondering.

Answer (score 7):

`findAny` (which is preferable to `findFirst` if you do not need ordering) and `anyMatch` are [short-circuiting operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description), which means they can return early without consuming the entire stream if the conditions allow. This is mentioned and linked in their method [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-). `count()` [is not](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--).

If the stream's final stage still uses a spliterator with the [SIZED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#SIZED) characteristic then `count()` *may* be as fast as the other two options. But this is a far weaker property than short-circuiting since intermediate stream operations – such as `filter()` – are very likely to discard the SIZED aspect.

All this information can be gleaned from the package documentation, it's highly recommended reading.

Comment: Since the code of the question incorporates a `filter` operation, there is no way around testing each element to get the number of matching elements. Except that the Hotspot optimizer might detect (in a sequential context) that calculating the count is not necessary given how the resulting number is used. In either case, `count` is the worst bet.

Comment: @Holger I have not claimed otherwise. I just wanted to mention that under limited circumstances `count` may be just as fast. A thinkable optimization would be something like a `.filter(Predictate.TRUE)` (if it existed) preserving the source spliterator.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that the circumstances under which a predictable size might be available are well known (which is why I left it off my answer as it’s not applicable here), and well, an always-`true` predicate does not exist, which might not be so dramatic, but even worse, in Oracle’s JRE/OpenJDK, the known number from `SIZED` spliterators is not used until Java 9…

Comment: granted, it is rather theoretical