# Java Streams: filter().count() vs anyMatch()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to find if a stream of strings has at least one occurrence of another `String` in a `Set<String>`. I came up with two solutions.

Performance wise, which approach is the best/recommended?

1)

```
return source.stream().filter(this::streamFilter).count() > 0;
```

2)

```
return source.stream().anyMatch(this::streamFilter);
```

Here's streamFilter method:

```
private boolean streamFilter(String str) {
    return filterKeywords.contains(str.toLowerCase());
}
```

filterKeywords: `private Set<String> filterKeywords;`

Or is there better approach than this?

Comment: #2 because it stops searching when the result is definitive. As the javadoc says: *This is a [**short-circuiting** terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).*

Comment: @Andreas I also thought so, wanted to be sure :)

Comment: See [Is Java 8 findFirst().isPresent() more efficient than count() > 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39713964/2711488)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `anyMatch(this::streamFilter)`, look at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) on the `anyMatch` method below (emphasis mine) as **it may not evaluate all elements** of the stream where as `count()` obviously iterates the whole stream of elements.

> Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided
>   predicate. **May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not
>   necessary for determining the result**. If the stream is empty then
>   false is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.

The point is some of the stream methods like `findFirst()`, `anyMatch()`, `findAny()`, etc.. perform **short-circuiting operations** i.e., they may not evaluate all elements of the stream and you can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

anyMatch doesn't always execute  all the stream. It is the best approach.